# Login Screen SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have TextFields for Login and SecureField for Password.
How can I go to another view when my Login and Password are correct?

```
struct LoginBoard: View {
@State private var login = "Tony"
@State private var password = "1234"

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack { 
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Enter Login and Password")
            }

            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                TextField("Login", text: $login)
            }
            
            HStack {
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            }
            
            Button("Login") {
                   
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very vague but it is usually with an `if else`. Hard to help since you don't have any code on verification or alternate screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Stacks inside a NavigationView{} and use a NavigationLink{} to direct to another view. Sample code is below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginBoard: View { 

    @State private var login = "Tony"
    @State private var password = "1234"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Enter Login and Password")
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        TextField("Login", text: $login)
                    }              
                    HStack {
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    }
                    NavigationLink {
                        WelcomeView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Login")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                    .disabled((login == "Tony" && 
                               password == "1234") ? false : true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WelcomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("welcome!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. My LoginBoard is a part of MainView with background of short video in loop. Without NavigationView{} I can see video in background, but when I add NavigationView{} I can see only white background without video. Do you how I can fix it?

Comment: Where is the video placed? NavigationView{ VIDEO { ZStack { LoginView? Let me know

Comment: var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        PlayerView() // video loop
    }
    ZStack {
        LoginBoard() // I added NavigationView and NavigationLink here
    }
}

Comment: NavigationView should be a top View as much as possible. Try this.
NavigationView { ZStack { Video().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all), something else } }

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NavigationView` that's an equivalent to navigation controller in UIKit and use NavigationLink as the segue or trigger for navigation.

```
struct LoginBoard: View {
 
    @State private var login = "Tony"
    @State private var password = "1234"
    @State isLoginSuccess = false

    var body: some View {
    // like navigation controller 
    // that handles the navigation of views
 
        NavigationView { 
        // DestinationView is the view will go 
        // to if credentials is correct
            NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(), 
                              isActive: $isLoginSuccess) { }
            ZStack { 
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Enter Login and Password")
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        TextField("Login", text: $login)
                    }            
                    HStack {
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    }
                    Button("Login") {
                    // if user and password are correct change          
                    // isLoginSuccess to true and will navigate 
                    // to the next View 
                        isLoginSuccess = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```